# Get a value from @href attribute

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scrapping a website that have a system pagination based on javascript, so I want to extract the page number from the @href attribute, this is how the link look:

```
<a href="javascript:AllerAPage('1', 'element_id');">Page 1</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scrapy selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) support [regular expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions):

```
sel.xpath('//a/@href').re(r"javascript:AllerAPage\('(\d+)',")
```

Note that `//a/@href` xpath exression is an example one - you may have a different one.

Demo shows the work of the regex I've provided:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "javascript:AllerAPage('1', 'element_id');"
>>> re.search("javascript:AllerAPage\('(\d+)',", s).group(1)
'1'
```